# Create a box with border on twitter bootstrap using css3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive box in twitter bootstrap exactly like this:

[image]

Now, I have created a `coloumn`:

```
<div class="col-lg-4" style="border-style: solid;">
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Data</p> 

</div>
```

Giving border to all of this doesn't work. What would be the best way fellas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe? [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/129689)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">

    <h2 class="title">Python Native Datatypes</h2>

        <div class="box">
            <ul>
                <li>Data</li>
                <li>Data</li>
                <li>Data</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
border: solid 1px #000;
padding: 10px;
z-index:0;
position: relative;
width:90%;
margin: -20px auto 0 auto;
}
.box li {
list-style: none;
}
.title {
background:green;
z-index:1;
position: relative;
padding: 5px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 200;
}
```